# Cannot layout CALayer frame correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer, shadow

I'm trying to set the frame of some CALayers but when I run this code they appear shifted to the right.

The frame coordinates and the shadows are correct.
I use this class as a UIView class from a view in storyboard.

```
class Shadows: UIView {

    let darkShadow = CALayer()
    let lightShadow = CALayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        shadows()
    }

    private func shadows() {
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 30
        let shadowRadius: CGFloat = 8

        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.masksToBounds = false

        darkShadow.frame = frame
        darkShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        darkShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        darkShadow.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        darkShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowRadius, height: shadowRadius)
        darkShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        darkShadow.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.insertSublayer(darkShadow, at: 0)

        lightShadow.frame = frame
        lightShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        lightShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        lightShadow.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        lightShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowRadius, height: -shadowRadius)
        lightShadow.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        lightShadow.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.insertSublayer(lightShadow, at: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple fix for your issue provide the `bounds` instead of the `frame` as the frame for the `CALayer`, here's how:

```swift
darkShadow.frame = bounds
```

To understand how this works you need to know the basics of `UIKit` layout and the difference between `frame` and `bounds` (You might wanna google this). In simple words, frame is the coordinates of the view with respect to super and bounds is with respect to itself.

Note: (I'm adding this here just as a guideline) It's a common beginner mistake. There are plenty of online resources that explain the difference between frame and bounds. Although you might find it a bit overwhelming in the beginning you will get to know the difference eventually. Here are the ones I found useful and could be helpful for you as well :- [Youtube Video of Saun Alen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfzy1qgxSAg) and [Article from hacking with swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/whats-the-difference-between-frame-and-bounds).